RuntimeError: "Unused kwargs" and "frozenset object has no attribute discard" with BitsAndBytes bf16 Quantized Model in Hugging Face Gradio App
I'm encountering a RuntimeError while running a BitsAndBytes bf16 quantized Gemma-2-2b model on Hugging Face Spaces with a Gradio UI. The error specifically mentions unused kwargs and an AttributeError with a frozenset.
Error Message:
Runtime Error
Exit code: 1. Reason: Unused kwargs: ['_load_in_4bit', '_load_in_8bit', 'quant_method']. These kwargs are not used in <class 'transformers.utils.quantization_config.BitsAndBytesConfig'>.
...
available_devices.discard("cpu") ** # Only Intel CPU is supported by BNB at the moment
AttributeError: 'frozenset' object has no attribute 'discard'
Code
Here's my app.py:
import gradio as gr
from huggingface_hub import InferenceClient
from transformers import AutoTokenizer, AutoModelForCausalLM

css = """
html, body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
}
body::before {
    content: '';
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
    background-image: url('https://png.pngtree.com/background/20230413/original/pngtree-medical-color-cartoon-blank-background-picture-image_2422159.jpg');
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    opacity: 0.60;
    background-position: center;
    z-index: -1;
}
.gradio-container {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    height: 100vh;
}
"""

model_id = "harishnair04/Gemma-medtr-2b-sft"
tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained(model_id)
gemma_model = AutoModelForCausalLM.from_pretrained(model_id)
tokenizer.pad_token_id = tokenizer.eos_token_id

def respond(input1):
    template = "Instruction:\n{instruction}\n\nResponse:\n{response}"
    inputs = tokenizer(input1, return_tensors="pt")
    out = gemma_model.generate(**inputs, temperature=0.4, do_sample=True, max_new_tokens=200)
    return tokenizer.decode(out[0], skip_special_tokens=True)

chat_interface = gr.Interface(
    respond,
    inputs="text",
    outputs="text",
    title="MT CHAT",
    description="Gemma 2b finetuned on medical transcripts",
    css=css
)

chat_interface.launch()

And here’s my requirements.txt:
huggingface_hub==0.25.2
gradio
transformers>=4.45.1
torch
gguf>=0.10.0
sentencepiece
numpy==1.21.0
bitsandbytes
accelerate>=0.26.0
https://github.com/bitsandbytes-foundation/bitsandbytes/releases/download/continuous-release_multi-backend-refactor/bitsandbytes-0.44.1.dev0-py3-none-manylinux_2_24_x86_64.whl


What I Tried

Double-checked that all required libraries and versions in requirements.txt are compatible.
Looked into the _load_in_4bit, _load_in_8bit, and quant_method warnings, which seem unused in the BitsAndBytesConfig.
Tried removing fp16 to avoid precision conflicts, assuming bfloat16 would handle quantization on its own.

Question
What should I adjust in my setup to avoid the Unused kwargs and frozenset error? Is there an update or compatibility fix required for BitsAndBytesConfig in this context?
Any insights on proper setup or dependencies are appreciated!
